# Nilpotent matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

[image]

This is from Axler's 1996 "Down with Determinants," I do not see why this basis would give the desired matrix representation. I would appreciate any help in seeing this.

Comment: If it is zero below the main diagonal then it is upper triangular. And nilpotent matrices are just that.

Comment: Because $T(\ker T^n) \subseteq \ker T^{n-1}$.

Comment: @Shogun There are nilpotent matrices that are not of that form! They are alway similar to a strict upper triangular matrix, but that is what the op wants to understand.

Comment: @Joppy I am sorry. I just realized before your last comment that nilpotent matrices can have rank less than $n$. But Thanks. :)

Comment: It's quite easy to see that. Ker $T$ will have alteast one Linearly independent vector(L.I.V.), and the rank of $T$ $\leq$ $n-1$. Now, when you compose $T$ with $T$, then Rank of $T^2$ $\leq$ $n-2$. and Therefore, you can find atleast two L.I.V's such that they will form a basis for Ker $T$. You can proceed like this and you will prove the lemma.

Comment: I could have worded it better. Im walking. I mostly was trying to say there is probably a duplicate if you search for nilpotent representation as upper triangular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nilpotent operator have a basis respresentation that is strictly upper triangular?, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532372/are-strictly-upper-triangular-matrices-nilpotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003525/nilpotent-operator-have-a-basis-respresentation-that-is-strictly-upper-triangula, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532372/are-strictly-upper-triangular-matrices-nilpotent)

Comment: @Shogun Thanks. I have flagged it.